# enable to include parent folder's file in php

Tags: php

The answer is already given but it is not satisfied.
This is my directory structure and I am trying to include the `header.php` in `index.php`

```
-my_app
   -assets
     -js
       -my_app.js
     -css
       -my_app.css

   -includes
    -header.php

   -index.php
-test
  -my_test.php
```

I tried with `include '../includes/header.php';` 
but is not working.I also want to include my_app.js file in index.php file.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
include 'includes/header.php';
```

`includes` and `index.php` are in same folder.

The path will be - `../assets/css/my_app.css`

Comment: I have edited my question.will you help me to use my_app.css file in header.php?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do `include 'includes/header.php';`, but I would recommend doing something like `include __DIR__ . '/includes/header.php';`.
For `my_app.js`, use this: `include 'assets/js/my_app.js';`.

Comment: I have edited my question.will you help me to use my_app.css file in header.php?

Answer (score 0):

```
include 'includes/header.php';

include 'assets/js/my_app.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically in all operating systems:

1. to call/include neghbour files and direcotories, simply call the their names
2. to call/include the files and direcotories resideing in the neighbour directories, proceed with the hirearchical approach
3. to call/include files that are in the upper levels, for each uplevel you need to use one `../` to access to a higher level direcotory and then go on with the process in the second item

Answer (score 0):

Im Sure you need your header.php, so dont use include (You got no error and no script-break if the include fails. Also im sure you need the header only once ;)

```
require_once('/includes/header.php');
```

for CSS/JS use sinply `../` to go one step higher :)

Br